# How to barf double quotes

Tags: emacs, paredit

I've got this as an initial state:

```
"first" second
```

Placing the cursor anywhere within the double quotes and pressing C-→ (in Emacs) gives me:

```
"first second"
```

Is there a "one-click" way to "barf" double quotes (i.e. to get back from the second state to the first)? I expected double quotes to work analogously to parenthesis barfing, but pressing C-← (while still having the cursor on the first word) doesn't seem to work (as it would in the case of parenthesis).

A potentially related question: Is there a way to remove the double quotes without prior making the length of their "span" zero.

Emacs 25.2 (9.0)

Major mode: Lisp

Enabled minor modes:
Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Column-Number Eldoc File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Eldoc
Global-Font-Lock Global-Hl-Line Global-Linum Global-Rainbow-Delimiters
Ido-Ubiquitous Line-Number Linum Mouse-Wheel Paredit Projectile
Projectile-Global Rainbow-Delimiters Recentf Save-Place Shell-Dirtrack
Show-Paren Tooltip Transient-Mark

Comment: Please consider editing your question to describe what major-modes and minor-modes you are using, so that readers do not have to guess by looking at the `paredit` tag.  The behavior described does not happen with `emacs -q` in a `fundamental-mode` buffer.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, this works exactly as your example describes it working "ideally". e.g starting with `"first second"` barfing gives me `"first" second`, and then slurping gives me `"first second"` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one-key command to do it.  But you can get close: if the point is at the | in `"first| second"`, you can do M-S C-M-d M-s:

1. M-S (paredit-split-sexp) to split it into `"first"| " second"`,
2. C-M-d (paredit-forward-down) to descend into tho following string giving `"first" "| second"`, and then
3. M-s (paredit-splice-sexp) to splice the content of the string giving `"first" | second`.

To clean up the spaces you can then do M-SPC (just-one-space).

`"first| second"`

M-S (paredit-split-sexp)

`"first"| " second"`

C-M-d (paredit-forward-down)

`` "first"  "| second"` ``

M-s (paredit-splice-sexp)

`"first" | second`

M-SPC (just-one-space)

`"first" |second`